# Autodesk Forge: Loading PDF does not trigger onItemLoadSuccess

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

We have an application running that currently works with both 3D and 2D files, and do not experience any issues when loading 3D files and DWG.

But when trying to load a PDF neither my "onItemLoadSuccess" or "onItemLoadFail" gets run

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized() {

    // Select the container for the viewer
    viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication(container);

    // Load settings, i.e extension manager
    viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, 
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D, { extensions: [ 'ExtensionManager'] });

    // Select model to load defined by URN 
    viewerApp.loadDocument(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
  });
}

function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
  var viewables = viewerApp.bubble.search({ 'type': 'geometry' });
  if (viewables.length === 0) {
    console.error('Document contains no viewables.');
    return;
  }

  // Choose any of the avialble viewables
  viewerApp.selectItem(viewables[0], onItemLoadSuccess, onItemLoadFail);
}

function onItemLoadSuccess(viewer, item) {
  console.log('onItemLoadSuccess()!');
}

function onItemLoadFail(errorCode) {
  console.error('onItemLoadFail() - errorCode:' + errorCode);
}
```

The PDF file will still open and load, so I am wondering if there might be a different way to run an onItemLoadSuccess function, or we have to do something a bit differently to ensure that our PDF's also gets loaded correctly.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Viewer v6.3 you can load PDF directly with `Autodesk.PDF` and pass in callbacks to `loadModel` like you do other models:

```
  Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {
    viewer.start()
    viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.PDF').then(function() {
        viewer.loadModel('/path/to/pdf', { page: 1 }, onLoadSuccess, onLoadFail);
    });
  });
```

See release notes here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v-63

Comment: Thank you! I will try. I however have some issues finding the path to my PDF placed on Bim360, because the URN is not sufficient here, correct?

Comment: No worries. You can follow the steps here to find the url to your items: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/

Comment: 1 step further. I now get two errors: Uncaught TypeError: l.createNativeFontFace is not a function and Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'polygon' of null - any idea what could be the reason for these?

Comment: I am afraid that’s not enough for me to get down to the bottom of your issue with these error messages alone. Can you show us your code in question like on with jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry for getting back late, but have just done a bit more testing of it. Seems it is having problems as soon as there is text on in the PDF. Is this a known issue? Or does it only support a certain list of fonts? When there is not text, then it works like a charm!

Comment: After some more testing i found that is was not all fonts that had an issue (read my comment for Michaels answer.

Comment: -phillippe - yes, the pdf support is quite limited at the moment.  So a very limited subset of pdf primitives are support.  Hence why you are seeing messed up results with certain pdf files.  The viewing team are working to get feature parity with pdf.js.  This includes better font support.  

@EsbenCN - Can you provide an example of what you are seeing (maybe DM me with a PDF file and a screenshot) ?   I can then take that to the team so they can prioritize it. Cheers Michael

Comment: @michaelbeale, I may be blind, but I can't see I can DM you here - Sorry! :)
But it is pretty simple; when I load a PDF containing just lines, no problem! When I load a PDF with only 'Times New Roman', no problem! But when I load a PDF with f.eks. a font called 'Roboto', then the loading will begin, but the console will write either "l.createNativeFontFace is not a function" or "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'polygon' of null" and stop the loading. In some file whatever is not that font may already have been loaded and showing, but loading will not continue.

Comment: Forge.help@autodesk.com

Comment: Thank you! Email send, and i will close this question! Thank you for all the help - hope i will get an answer and get it working!

Answer (score 0):

(Adding to Bryan's answer...)

I wrote a blog post about this.  Take a look at the DEMO and sample code to  help answer your question about 'onItemLoadSuccess / onItemLoadFail' events.

BLOG: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/fast-pdf-viewingmarkup-inside-forge-viewer

DEMO: https://wallabyway.github.io/offline-pdf-markup/

Hope that helps!

[image]

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the PDF files the viewer can load, the samples that are in that repo work fine, but some of my files produce a messed up result... I logged an issue on your repo but no response :'( https://github.com/wallabyway/offline-pdf-markup/issues/2

Comment: After further testing and making sure i load v6.4 i now seem to only have issue with "non-standard" fonts. Do you know if there is a list of "accepted" fonts some where, or any idea if there is a plan to handle some kind of fall-back function for unknown fonts?